# Rails4 route with scope and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes, rails-i18n

quite new to Ruby and Rails, so it's probably a dumb question ;)

I try to get a "i18n" route working with an "admin" namespace.

So, my routes file looks like

```
scope '/:locale' do
  root 'admin#index', as: :root
  namespace :admin do
    resources :foos
  end
end
```

In my ApplicationController, I have

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

If I "rake routes", I got the following

```
root GET    /                     admin#index
     GET    /:locale(.:format)    admin#index
admin_foos GET    /:locale/admin/foos(.:format)  admin/foos#index
```

And I can reach /en/admin/foos

The problem I'm facing, is that if I print a path within a view, (even the path from my form, ...) I will get the path /admin/foo?locale=en. And this url with end with a 404.

The calls to the path are simple such

```
<%= link_to 'Back', admin_foos_path %>
```

I guess I'm missing something, but have no idea of what.
Any help will be appreciated !

Regards,
Benjamin

Comment: Odd.  Perhaps post some of your view code that generates those off URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
admin_foos_path :locale => 'en'
admin_foo_path :id => @foo.id, :locale => 'en'
```

etc...

If you generate your URLs like that, should do the trick.